# CSS hover div and link at the same time

Tags: html, css, hover

This forum is great and saved me tons of time already,
It's a relatively simple matter, but i've been cracking my head all day, and can't find a solution.

It's essentially a div made to look like a "button", with size, background and borders defined.
I'm trying to get both the link and the div's borders/background to light up when hovering on it, to no avail.
I can only get one of them to change, either the link or the "button"

so the html:

```
<div align="middle" class="main_button1"><a href="/about/">Learn more</a></div>
```

and the div style is:

```
.main_button1 {
    margin: auto;
    line-height: 2;
    width: 180px;
    border: 3px solid #98a2a7;
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 22px;
    background: white;
}

.main_button1 a {
    color: #98a2a7;
}

.main_button1 a:visited { 
    color: #98a2a7; 
}
```

but whenever i try to define the hover effect:
`.main_button1:hover` won't affect the link
and
`.main_button1 a:hover` won't affect the div, only the link

here's my futile attempt, which only changes the div color and not the link

```
.main_button1:hover { 
    border: 3px solid #98a2a7;
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 22px;
    background: #98a2a7;

    a { color: red; }
}
```

Any suggestions please oh wisemen (and wisewomen) ?
thanks in advance!

Comment: are you using scss?

Comment: what you have now appears to work https://codepen.io/mcoker/pen/qjZzeW

Comment: It is important that we know if you are using scss/less or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/ash06229/qaouthjf/

```css
.main_button1 {
  margin: auto;
  line-height: 2;
  width: 180px;
  border: 3px solid #98a2a7;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 22px;
  background: white;
}

.main_button1 a {
  color: #98a2a7;
}

.main_button1 a:visited{ 
  color: #98a2a7;
}

.main_button1:hover { 
  border: 3px solid #98a2a7;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 22px;
  background: #98a2a7;
}

.main_button1:hover a { 
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div align="middle" class="main_button1"><A HREF="/about/">Learn more</A></div>
```

Comment: that did the trick! for the love of god i have no idea how come it didn't work for me before. thanks!!

Answer (score 3):

You have your anchor tag style inside the hover rule. Put it outside in a new rule like this.

```css
  .main_button1 {
margin: auto;
line-height: 2;
width: 180px;
border: 3px solid #98a2a7;
padding: 10px;
border-radius: 22px;
background: white;
}

.main_button1 a{
color: #98a2a7;
}

.main_button1 a:visited{ 
color: #98a2a7; }

.main_button1:hover { 
border: 3px solid #98a2a7;
padding: 10px;
border-radius: 22px;
background: #98a2a7;

}

.main_button1:hover  a{color: red;}
```

```html
<div align="middle" class="main_button1"><a HREF="/about/">Learn more</a></div>
```

Comment: depends if the OP is using a css preprocessor or not

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply CSS to both, together

```
.main_button1:hover, .main_button1 a:hover {border: 3px solid #98a2a7; padding:10px; border-radius: 22px; background: #98a2a7;}
```

Comment: that doesn't work for me .. the above answers have done it though. thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like you were coding in SCSS. Perhaps you got confused, anyway, I simply translated the SCSS to regular CSS:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OgNKPg

```css
.main_button1 {
  margin: auto;
  line-height: 2;
  width: 180px;
  border: 3px solid #98a2a7;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 22px;
  background: white;
}

.main_button1 a {
  color: #98a2a7;
}

.main_button1 a:visited {
  color: #98a2a7;
}
.main_button1:hover {
  border: 3px solid #98a2a7;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 22px;
  background: #98a2a7;
}
.main_button1:hover a {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div align="middle" class="main_button1"><A HREF="/about/">Learn more</A></div>
```

However, even better is to make the  element itself the button: 
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/RgaXPG

```css
.main_button1 {
  margin: auto;
  line-height: 2;
  width: 180px;
  border: 3px solid #98a2a7;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 22px;
  background: white;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
}

.main_button1 {
  color: #98a2a7;
}

.main_button1:visited {
  color: #98a2a7;
}
.main_button1:hover {
  border: 3px solid #98a2a7;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 22px;
  background: #98a2a7;
}
.main_button1:hover  {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<A HREF="/about/" class="main_button1">Learn more</A>
```

Have fun!